# Select the stepper motor driver

Tags: stepper-motor, driver

I need to know the difference between these two motors in inductance values and their operations.

1. (1A) current/Phase, 6V, 60mH
2. (.5A) current/Phase, 12V, 110mH

In many resources, it has been mentioned, the driver output inductance parameters should satisfy the motor inductance. But in none of the stepper motor datasheets, this ability is not mentioned. I need to know the effect of inductance on the motor operation and how to select the best driver for my stepper motor regarding the inductance.

Comment: I have just read some stepper driver datasheets and agree that motor inductance is not mentioned as a limiting factor. My understanding and experience is, that if the driver can handle the phase current and voltage with proper margin it can also handle the inductance. However, 60 mH and 110 mH are unusual high values. Can you please provide a motor datasheet, just for curiosity?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. you can see this https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/nema-23-stepper-0-9nm-127-43oz-in-w-brake-friction-torque-2-0nm-283oz-in-23hm20-0384d-b200

Comment: With 12 V only and 110 mH phase inductance this motor will be slow. What is your intended step frequency?

Comment: I need to rotate this motor with 300RPM or 60Khz.

Comment: For 300 rpm you need 2 kHz at the coils. I may be wrong, but I estimate, that you need more than 200 V supply voltage for this step frequency with 110 mH phase inductance.

Comment: I do the same calculation, for this motor as I mentioned, the frequency should be 12.5us, and then the total voltage 8800 volts. I get confused too.